# Nested property in Maven profile for plugin configuration

Tags: java, maven, nested-properties

I have a Java EE 7 project which is deployed to WildFly 8.1.0-Final. I use a standalone Wildfly server managed by Maven (i.e., clean configuration on every `mvn clean`) for testing, and the "normal" server remotely.

In order to deploy to both servers with the maven-wildfly-plugin (1.0.2.Final), I have configured two Maven profiles: **wildfly-local**, which defines local username, password, and port number; and **wildfly-remote**, which defines remote username, password, and port number.

However, the remote server runs in **domain mode**, while the local server does not. Thus, I am required to define a domain configuration with a server-group for the remote server, like so:

```
...
<plugin>
  <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>

  <configuration>
    <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
    <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
    <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
    <domain>
      <server-groups>
        <server-group>${wildfly-server-group}</server-group>
      </server-groups>
    </domain>
  </configuration>
  ...
</plugin>
...
```

`${wildfly-hostname}` and the three other proiperties are defined in the profile, and this configuration works. However, the standalone, non-"domain mode" local test server does not allow deployment of an application where a server-group is defined at all.

My first thought was to define a nested property in the remote profile, like so:

```
<profile>
  <id>wildfly-remote</id>
  <properties>
    ...
    <wildfly-domain>
      <server-groups>
        <server-group>*my server group name*</server-group>
      </server-groups>
    </wildfly-domain>
    ...
    </properties>
</profile>
```

... and a simple property in the local profile, like so:

```
<profile>
  <id>wildfly-local</id>
  <properties>
    <wildfly-domain/>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Maven does not like this because it cannot parse tags where text is expected.

Is there any way of defining a "resource" which is nested in one Maven profile, but flat in another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties are just simple key-value pairs, the value can't be parsed as markup.

Move the entire configuration into the profile instead.